# Flutter: how to makeline chart inside a sized box?

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to make a percent indicator and a line chart inside a sized box like this

[image]

but when i add the line chart not compact to the sized box,
it shows error in the sized box with an error with the widht, i'm fairly new to flutter this is my first time using a chart.

Code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/circular_percent_indicator.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';

class Data5 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Data5({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 270,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [Linechart()],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Circular extends StatelessWidget {
  const Circular({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: CircularPercentIndicator(
        radius: 100,
        lineWidth: 15.0,
        percent: 1.00,
        center: Text(
          "TF",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 40),
        ),
        progressColor: Color.fromRGBO(37, 150, 190, 1),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Linechart extends StatelessWidget {
  const Linechart({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<SalesData> chartData = [
      SalesData("Jan", 0),
      SalesData("Feb", 0),
      SalesData("Mar", 0),
      SalesData("Apr", 0),
      SalesData("May", 3),
      SalesData("June", 10),
      SalesData("Jul", 85),
      SalesData("Aug", 25),
      SalesData("Sept", 5),
      SalesData("Oct", 2),
      SalesData("Nov", 0),
      SalesData("Dec", 0)
    ];

    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Center(
            child: Container(
                child: SfCartesianChart(
                    primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(),
                    series: <ChartSeries>[
              // Renders line chart
              LineSeries<SalesData, String>(
                  dataSource: chartData,
                  xValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => sales.Month,
                  yValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => sales.sales)
            ]))));
  }
}

class SalesData {
  SalesData(this.Month, this.sales);
  final String Month;
  final int sales;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: when i try to put the line chart inside the sizedbox it didn't show the line, sometimes it has an error on the right side of the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is updated class, You can change lots of thing with a little research on your Syncfunction charts.

[image]

```
Container(
    height: 200,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    ),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Center(
        child: Row(
      children: [
        const CircleAvatar(
            radius: 30,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 22,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              child: Text('TF'),
            )),
        Container(
            child: SfCartesianChart(
                title: ChartTitle(
                    text: 'TREND EVENT 2022',
                    alignment: ChartAlignment.near,
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    )),
                primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
                primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(maximum: 100),
                tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: true),
                series: <ChartSeries>[
              LineSeries<SalesData, String>(
                  markerSettings: const MarkerSettings(isVisible: true),
                  enableTooltip: true,
                  dataSource: chartData,
                  xValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => sales.Month,
                  yValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => sales.sales)
            ])),
      ],
    )))
```

Comment: Thank you so much it finally work the line already in the box

Answer (score 0):

```
 child: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
           Expanded(child: Linechart() ) // wrap your line chart with expanded
           ],
        ),
      ),
```